# How to use Boost BLAS in Eigen

Tags: boost, eigen, ublas

[This page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html) says that you can specify what BLAS libary Eigen should use. I'd like to use [the Boost version of BLAS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html) but have been able to get it to link. It is missing a lot of symbols, such as daxpy_, dgemv_ and dtrmv_. From what I can see, these are functions in Intel's MKL, which I don't want. I have been unable to find instructions for or examples of using Boost BLAS with Eigen on the Web. Does anyone know of any?

P.S. - Boost BLAS is header only, so the comments in the Eigen docs that discuss linking in BLAS libraries are irrelevant in my case.

Comment: It does not work that way. Eigen's BLAS support is for linking against external libraries, not header-only libraries. Among other things, Eigen declares the function prototypes itself, mostly because the original BLAS and LAPACK are Fortran libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boost uBLAS provides the equivalent functionality, but it is not a "BLAS library".

What Eigen, and all other software that requires a BLAS library, requires is a library that supports the standard BLAS ABI. The very page you link even explicitly states this:

> any F77 compatible BLAS or LAPACK libraries

Boost uBLAS clearly is not such a library. It would require one to completely rewrite their code to only work with uBLAS. Eigen has not done so.

`daxpy_` and the other symbols like would be provided by a BLAS library, like MKL, OpenBLAS, BLIS and more.